# Sum two columns and show the columns which were added in postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four tables which I have joined and I know I have not joined using the desired way, but for now I am just trying to find a solution to it.

```
with cte as 
 (select
pw.noc_id as noc_id ,
sum(pw.amt) as Collected_AMT

from
tamsnoc.noc_basic_vw bw,
tamsnoc.noc_wf_vw nw,
pymt.noc_pymt_vw pw,
pymt.noc_available_for_pymt_vw nvp
where
pw.noc_id = bw.noc_id
and nw.object_id = bw.noc_id
and bw.noc_id = nvp.object_id
and bw.noc_id =874
and nvp.total_amt_due::numeric(65,
2) > 0::numeric
group by
pw.noc_id)
 SELECT distinct ct.noc_id,bw.scac_code as SCAC,
nvp.drn as DRN,
pw.new_overcharge_amt,
 ct.Collected_AMT,
 pw.check_no,
 to_char(pw.check_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as Check_date,
 pw.amt
 FROM tamsnoc.noc_basic_vw bw,
 tamsnoc.noc_wf_vw nw,
 pymt.noc_pymt_vw pw,
 pymt.noc_available_for_pymt_vw nvp,
 cte ct
 WHERE pw.noc_id = bw.noc_id 
 AND nw.object_id = bw.noc_id 
 AND bw.noc_id = nvp.object_id 
 and ct.noc_id=bw.noc_id
 AND nvp.total_amt_due::numeric(65,2) > 0::numeric
```

This is what I get from the output of the above query

[image]

But here how I want it

[image]

any solutions will be helpful

Comment: First of all, your expected o/p has columns different from what you have written in your query

Comment: I know it is different, I am worried about amount and collected amount, collected amount is the sum version of amount